# Setting page numbers in bottom center in classicthesis (two-sided page)

Tags: page-numbering, classicthesis

The library of my school has asked to revise my thesis and put all the page numbers in bottom center. I have written my thesis using `classicthesis`. I am using the following options in my document.

```
\documentclass[
            twoside, 
            openright,
            titlepage, numbers=noenddot, headinclude,
            footinclude=true,  
            cleardoublepage=empty,
            BCOR=30mm, paper=letter, fontsize=11pt, 
            dottedtoc, 
            ngerman, american, 
            listof=totoc, 
            ]{scrreprt} 


\PassOptionsToPackage{
                eulerchapternumbers,
                listings,
                pdfspacing,
                subfig,
                beramono,
                parts}{classicthesis}
```

I commented out `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` and used `\pagestyle{plain}` instead of that and it did not help. In the manual of `KOMA–Script Package` it is mentioned that

> If you use the option `twoside`, page numbers will be set into the outer margins,
>   otherwise they will be centered. `scrbook` has twoside as the default.

I was able to partially solve this problem by using the following.

```
\deftripstyle{pgnumbottomcenter}{}{}{}{}{\pagemark{}}{}
\pagestyle{pgnumbottomcenter}
```

It works perfectly except for the first page of each chapter as well as some of the pages of preliminary sections such as table of content. In fact, page number is placed at the outer margin. In the following , you can find the result of using this command.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Could someone help me how I can force `scrreprt` to place the page numbers at bottom center for all the pages when `twoside` option is being used? I would be grateful for any help (I need to submit my thesis as soon as possible)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that first pages of chapters and similar ones (ToC, etc.) use the `plain` style even when you redefine the global style.

In KOMA-script classes this behavior can be changed modifying the meaning of `\chapterpagestyle` to be `pgnumbottomcenter`, i.e.

```
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{pgnumbottomcenter}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[
            twoside,
            openright,
            titlepage, numbers=noenddot, headinclude,
            footinclude=true,
            cleardoublepage=empty,
            BCOR=30mm, paper=letter, fontsize=11pt,
            listof=totoc,
            ]{scrreprt}


\PassOptionsToPackage{
                eulerchapternumbers,
                listings,
                pdfspacing,
                subfig,
                beramono,
                parts}{classicthesis}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{scrpage2}

\deftripstyle{pgnumbottomcenter}{}{}{}{}{\pagemark{}}{}
\pagestyle{pgnumbottomcenter}
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{pgnumbottomcenter}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]